# Adding Fields in an attribute table ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I want to add new field each time my loop needs to add fields but the name of the field should be different, like increment of characters. But it always rises and exception error stating a field with same name has been created already and it creates only one field when the loop runs 3 times.

```
for j in range(3):
...     tab_field=arcpy.AddField_management("prob_table","day(x)","LONG")
...     for k in range(6):
...         for i in range(4):
...             a=arr_trans[k][i][j]
...             print(a)
...     x+=1
```

here x is defined as 0 initially before the starting of the loop. This is not the full code im working on but the necessary part of code which illustrates when a new field is to be created.

```
r=0 
x=0
for j in range(3):
    c=0
    tab_field=arcpy.AddField_management("prob_table","day_{0}".format(x),"LONG")
    for k in range(6):
        for i in range(4):
            a=arr_trans[k][i][j]
            cursor=arcpy.updatecursor("prob_table","OID={}".format(c),fields="")
            for row in cursor:
                IR=row.getvalue("I_R")
                IN=row.getvalue("I_N")
                RR=row.getvalue("R_R")
                RN=row.getvalue("R_N")
                NR=row.getvalue("N_R")
                NN=row.getvalue("N_N")
                RW=row.getvalue("W_R")
                RD=row.getvalue("D_R")
                ND=row.getvalue("D_N")
                NW=row.getvalue("W_N")
                if(r==0):
                    if(a==0):
                        rain_prob=IR*RD
                        norain_prob=IN*ND
                        if(rain_prob>norain_prob):
                            row.setvalue("x",1)
                            updatecursor
                        else:
                            row.setvalue("x",0)
                            updatecursor
                    else:
                        rain_prob=IR*RW
                        norain_prob=IN*NW
                        if(rain_prob>norain_prob):
                            row.setvalue("x",1)
                        else:
                            row.setvalue("x",0)
```

the "x" denotes the place i need to give my field name which doesnt work by using format(x). the error i get is an execution error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use parenthesis in a field name, it can cause problems.

This: `"day(x)"` wont change with each loop, is it just a static string. You need to do something like `"day_{0}".format(x)`.

And for the first loop x will be nothing (unless you define it before in the code you dont show). Add `x=0` Before the for loop

Comment: and if i want to access the same field or the previous field, consider still running inside the for loop, should i use the field name as .format(x) and .format(x-1) for current and previous fields respectively?

Comment: What do you mean by access?

Comment: like i am updating the cells in those fields as and when its created. so if i want to access data from say day_{0} when currently i am working on updating day_{1}? my question is if i can directly give it as day_{x-1} or should i use the general format again

Comment: Update using da.UpdateCursor, Field Calculator etc? You need to use the field name, for example `"day_{0}".format(x)` should work, and probably `"day_{0}".format(x-1)`. Hard to say without seeing the actual code.

Comment: nope that doesnt work...and yes in setValue format(x) and x-1 doesn't work. It gives an execution error. Actually the code it too big but ill post the first part in above.

Comment: It should work, I dont know what setValue is, are you using old cursor (not da.UpdateCursor)? Post it as a new question

Comment: no i am not using da.updatecursor and i have already edited here sorry